# VXML: Field input, forward typing

Tags: input, field, vxml, voicexml

**Situation**:

I have two VXML documents that are part of one flow. In the first document the user is prompted to enter a number (dtmf, max = 3 digits). The second document prompts the user to enter another number (dtmf, max = 10 digits).

**Problem**:

When the user is prompted to enter the first number and he enters 4 digits (e.g. 1234), the last number (4) is used as input for the second field.

**Expected**:

The last number must be ignored. I expect that a "nomatch" event is thrown because I define that the maxlength = 3.

**Document 1:**

```
<form>
<field name="input1" type="digits?minlength=1;maxlength=3">         
    <audio src="prompt1"/>          
    <filled>            
        <submit next="next.jsp" namelist="input1" />            
    </filled>
</field>
```

**Document 2:**

```
<form>
<field name="input2" type="digits?minlength=1;maxlength=10">            
    <audio src="prompt2"/>          
    <filled>            
        <submit next="next2.jsp" namelist="input2" />           
    </filled>
</field>
```

**Question:**
How can I solve this issue in VXML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set "termtimeout" property.

It means "[The terminating timeout to use when recognizing DTMF input.](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml6.3.3)"

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version="2.1">
    <form>
        <property name="termtimeout" value="0s" />
        <field name="input1" type="digits?minlength=1;maxlength=3">
            <filled>
                <submit next="next.jsp" namelist="input1" />
            </filled>
        </field>
    </form>
</vxml>
```